# Laravel - How can I used a different controller based on url parameters?

Tags: routes, laravel-5

I have a route that looks like this:

```
Route::get('/{camp}/session/{session}/athlete/{athlete}/category/{category}/type/{type}', 'AthleteController@chart');
```

This page renders a view that allows an athlete to choose the position (Kicker, Punter, Receiver etc). The "Position" is the `/type/{type}` part of the url. Based on the value of `{type}` If possible, I would like to use the appropriate controller.

For example, let's say `/type/2` is Kickoff. So to show the kickoff form this url:

```
/camp/123/session/456/athlete/5/category/1/type/2
```

Would use `KickoffController@create`. Then the `KickoffController@store` to save the data.

`/type/3` would be for punting:

```
/camp/123/session/456/athlete/5/category/1/type/3
```

So I would use `PuntController@create`; `PuntController@store` to save (and so on).

I suppose I could create a `StatController` and just keep expanding a switch based on type, but that seems...not as clean as having a 1:1 stat:controller.

I've looked around at dynamic routing. Is that I what I need here?

**EDIT**

This is what my form tag looks like using `Laravel Collective`:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action'=>'KickoffController@store','class'=>'charting-form')) !!}
```

Here is what I have tried based on the suggested answer and some other SO posts. (please keep the laughter to a minimum) :)

```
Route::post('/{camp}/session/{session}/athlete/{athlete}/category/{category}/type/{type}/store', function ($type) {

    switch ($type) {
        case 1:
            $stat = 'Kickoff';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    $class = 'App\Http\Controllers\/' . $stat . '\/Controller';
    $action = 'method';

    if (method_exists($class, $action . 'Action')) {
        $controller = App::make($class);
        return $controller->callAction($action, array());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the dynamic controller by

```
$controller_name = "App\Http\Controllers\\$controller_name";
return controller_name->method();
```

Comment: Hi Manash - Thank you for your suggestion! I have updated my question based on your answer. Unfortunately...I just don't understand.